# Is it possible to add multiple passwords under one account to Google Smart Lock?

Tags: email, passwords, google-smartlockpasswords

I have a slightly unusual use-case scenario with the Protonmail web client, though I am sure there are plenty of other examples of similar happening across the internet, likely especially where heightened security is concerned.

I have multiple passwords set up (which works essentially as an alternative to 2-factor authentication), one being for the initial account login, and the second for decrypting the mailbox. It is possible to have different mailboxes setup and give each one an individual decryption password.

Every time I log in I can proceed right past the initial login because Smart Lock has that password saved, but then when I manually enter the second password chrome asks me if I wish to "update my credentials", assuming that I have changed my password for that site or something.

So my question is, is it possible either to let Smart Lock know that there are two separate passwords that need saving, or failing that, somehow let it know that the second password is supplementary rather than a replacement.

Cheers.